# How do you write a web script to deal with urls of the form example.com/data/234 rather than example.com/data.php?id=234?

Tags: php, url, backbone.js

I'm use to working with `$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays in PHP scripts. I'm trying to learn Backbone (specifically the Backbone.sync function) and apparently it assumes that you'll set up your server so that *example.com/student/32053* retrieves the student with id 32053.

- How do I set up my scripts to do this?
- Doesn't *example.com/student/32053* load up index.* from the "32053" subdirectory of "student"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an Apache server, use the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module. In you `.htaccess` file, just specify a simple rule like:

```
^data/(\d+)$ data.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Doing this, when calling `example.com/data/100`, apache will internally call `example.com/data.php?id=100`.

Let me know if you need a similar example for Microsoft IIS.

Comment: could you post an example for IIS? I just developed this 2 page website and the owner has a Windows server, so I had to lose the rewrites. This is not a big loss, but it might help me in the future to know how to do rewrites on IIS. Thanks! Scalawag, sorry for interfering with your topic :).

Comment: @Sorin There is [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). In most respects it works exactly like Apache's mod_rewrite. The free version should be enough.

Comment: @Sorin Agreed with what Tomalak said. Maybe it's important to point out that ISAPI Rewrite is not the only solution on IIS.